# How do you access and store the values/properties of a "fulfilled" promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to build an object that renders details of a certain planet.  I use the fetch method and it returns a promise.  How do I get the values from the [[PromiseResult]] object in order to populate the details in "render()". I tried to call fetchPlanetData().then(data=>data.(any property) from the ${ } in render(they have placeholders now) but it always returns "undefined."  Thanks in advance.

```
class PlanetDetails {
  constructor(planet) {
    this.planet = planet;
    //this.fetchPlanetData();
    this.render();
  }

  async fetchPlanetData() {
    const result = await fetch(`https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/${this.planet}`);
    this.data = await result.json();
    return this.data;
  }

  render() {
    const hook = document.querySelector('.moons');
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'container';
    container.innerHTML = `
    <p>The average temperature is:${'averageTemp'}</p>
    <p>The escape velocityis:${'escape'}</p>
    <p>The gravity is ${'gravity'} times that of Earth's.</p>
        `;

    hook.append(container);
  }
}

const planetDetails = new PlanetDetails('neptune');

console.log(planetDetails.fetchPlanetData());``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting `this.render` in the constructor, make a new async method called `init` and call it from the constructor instead. `await` the data from `fetchPlanetData`, assign it to `this.data`, and *then* call `this.render`.

Note: it doesn't look like you're using any data from `this.data` in your render method. When you code `${'averageTemp'}` did you mean `${this.data.averageTemp}`, for example?

```
class PlanetDetails {

  constructor(planet) {
    this.planet = planet;
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    this.data = await this.fetchPlanetData();
    this.render();
  }

  async fetchPlanetData() {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    return result.json();
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Perfect!! And yes, I wanted to use "this.data.(specfiic property)" in the render method to inject my fields with properties returned from that API, and now I can, and AM! Thank you!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
await this.fetchPlanetData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this.fetchPlanetData() is an async function you need to resolve the Promise. So try this

```
console.log(await this.fetchPlanetData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing understanding of [Promises](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) and [Async Await](https://javascript.info/async-await). Added link for all for learning.

Promises are different from normal function calls, they don't return values like synchronous methods, they return response when they are fulfilled and code execution doesn't stop on Promise call, so How does promise returns data - Using two methods resolve and reject.

Async await is just a wrapper over promises to make promises look like synchronous code but behind the scenes it's always asynchronous.

---

In promises, you get either resolved or rejected after fulfilment and usually we put the data inside the resolve part and errors in reject part.
In async-await the same gets converted into `try...catch` blocks. As `return` a value `x` from an async function always means `Promise.resolve(x)` so this data can be used inside a `then` method or `try` block. And any `Promise.reject` or `throw` can be captured in the `catch` block.

```js
class PlanetDetails {
  constructor(planet) {
    this.planet = planet;
    this.resolvePlanetData();
  }

  async resolvePlanetData() {
    this.data = await this.fetchPlanetData();
    this.render();
  }

  async fetchPlanetData() {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(`https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/${this.planet}`);
      return await result.json();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const hook = document.querySelector('.moons');
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.className = 'container';
    container.innerHTML = `
    <p>The average temperature is: ${this.data.avgTemp}</p>
    <p>The escape velocityis: ${this.data.escape}</p>
    <p>The gravity is ${this.data.gravity} times that of Earth's.</p>
        `;

    hook.append(container);
  }
}

const planetDetails = new PlanetDetails('neptune');
```

```css
.moons {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="moons">

</div>
```

Notice that I have used `try...catch` in `fetchPlanetData` but not in `resolvePlanetData` because `fetch` or `.json()` can throw error or reject in many situations which is handled in try catch but I know that `fetchPlanetData` will always resolve as no throw is there so I can use it without`try...catch` safely.

Also, I am assuming you want to use `this.data` in render method hence updated the same.

Comment: But I mentioned about aync await as well, I got your point, I misunderstood the question but I don't think it deserves downvote though. :|